# How to cancel push notification in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, push-notification

I'm developing a notification application. User can enter bills with the due date. After that on the due date it'll show a notification. If user press cancel it should not display again.

I used `[app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];` in the cancel button event. But when it become from background state to foreground that notification still coming. How can I stop this when it comes to foreground after user clicking the cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

Once a push request has been sent to the Apple Push Notification servers, thats it. It disappears into their system and they will then try to deliver it on a 'best effort' basis. You receive no feedback about its status or any ability to change/delete it.

So , there is no way you can manipulate sent notifications as far as I know.